# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by pluggable.php

Tags: plugin-development, headers, wp-redirect

I'm trying to develop a simple plugin but I'm having a problem: I have a custom `WP_List_Table` in an admin page, but when I click on a button like "Edit Row" or "Delete Row" it performs some expected action and try to refresh the page using `wp_redirect()`. This is causing a problem:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php:5652) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1265

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php:5652) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1268
```

I have just the Advanced Custom Fields plugin installed and I'm using the default theme. At the moment, my plugin is JUST this code below (I got it here https://www.sitepoint.com/using-wp_list_table-to-create-wordpress-admin-tables/):

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}

class Customers_List extends WP_List_Table {

    /** Class constructor */
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct( [
            'singular' => __( 'Customer', 'sp' ), //singular name of the listed records
            'plural'   => __( 'Customers', 'sp' ), //plural name of the listed records
            'ajax'     => false //does this table support ajax?
        ] );

    }


    /**
    * Retrieve customers data from the database
    *
    * @param int $per_page
    * @param int $page_number
    *
    * @return mixed
    */
    public static function get_customers() {

        $result = array();

        $args = array(
            'role'    => 'Inscrito',
        );

        $users = get_users( $args );

        foreach($users as $user){

            $user_form = 'user_'. $user->ID;

            $image = get_field('receipt', $user_form);
            $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

            if( $image ) {
                $image_url = '<a href="' .$image['url'] . '"> a </a>';
            }else{
                $image_url = 'False';
            }

            array_push($result, 
                        array(  'ID' => $user->ID,
                                'name' => $user->status,
                                'address' => $image_url, 
                                'city' => $image_url, 
                        )
            );
        }

        return $result;
    }


    /**
    * Delete a customer record.
    *
    * @param int $id customer ID
    */
    public static function delete_customer( $id ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $wpdb->delete(
            "{$wpdb->prefix}customers",
            [ 'ID' => $id ],
            [ '%d' ]
        );
    }

    /** Text displayed when no customer data is available */
    public function no_items() {
        _e( 'No customers avaliable.', 'sp' );
    }


    /**
    * Render a column when no column specific method exist.
    *
    * @param array $item
    * @param string $column_name
    *
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
        switch ( $column_name ) {
            case 'address':
            case 'city':
                return $item[ $column_name ];
            default:
                return print_r( $item, true ); //Show the whole array for troubleshooting purposes
        }
    }

    /**
    * Render the bulk edit checkbox
    *
    * @param array $item
    *
    * @return string
    */
    function column_cb( $item ) {
        return sprintf(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="bulk-delete[]" value="%s" />', $item['ID']
        );
    }


    /**
    * Method for name column
    *
    * @param array $item an array of DB data
    *
    * @return string
    */
    function column_name( $item ) {

        $delete_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'sp_delete_customer' );

        $title = '<strong>' . $item['name'] . '</strong>';

        $actions = [
            'delete' => sprintf( '<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&customer=%s&_wpnonce=%s">Delete</a>', esc_attr( $_REQUEST['page'] ), 'delete', absint( $item['ID'] ), $delete_nonce )
        ];

        return $title . $this->row_actions( $actions );
    }


    /**
    *  Associative array of columns
    *
    * @return array
    */
    function get_columns() {
        $columns = [
            'cb'      => '<input type="checkbox" />',
            'name'    => __( 'Name', 'sp' ),
            'address' => __( 'Address', 'sp' ),
            'city'    => __( 'City', 'sp' )
        ];

        return $columns;
    }


    /**
    * Columns to make sortable.
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function get_sortable_columns() {
        $sortable_columns = array(
            'name' => array( 'name', true ),
            'city' => array( 'city', false )
        );

        return $sortable_columns;
    }

    /**
    * Returns an associative array containing the bulk action
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function get_bulk_actions() {
        $actions = [
            'bulk-delete' => 'Delete'
        ];

        return $actions;
    }


    /**
    * Handles data query and filter, sorting, and pagination.
    */
    public function prepare_items() {

        $this->_column_headers = $this->get_column_info();

        /** Process bulk action */
        $this->process_bulk_action();

        $users = self::get_customers();

        $per_page     = $this->get_items_per_page( 'customers_per_page', 5 );
        $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
        $total_items  = self::record_count();
        $slice_offset = ( ( $current_page-1 )* $per_page );
        $slice_limit = $slice_offset+$per_page;

        // only ncessary because we have sample data
        $found_data = array_slice( $users, $slice_offset, $slice_limit);

        $this->set_pagination_args( [
            'total_items' => $total_items, //WE have to calculate the total number of items
            'per_page'    => $per_page //WE have to determine how many items to show on a page
        ] );

        $this->items = $found_data;
    }

    public function process_bulk_action() {

        //Detect when a bulk action is being triggered...
        if ( 'delete' === $this->current_action() ) {

            // In our file that handles the request, verify the nonce.
            $nonce = esc_attr( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] );

            if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'sp_delete_customer' ) ) {
                die( 'Go get a life script kiddies' );
            }
            else {
                self::delete_customer( absint( $_GET['customer'] ) );

                        // esc_url_raw() is used to prevent converting ampersand in url to "#038;"
                        // add_query_arg() return the current url
                        wp_redirect( esc_url_raw(add_query_arg()) );
                exit;
            }

        }

        // If the delete bulk action is triggered
        if ( ( isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'bulk-delete' )
            || ( isset( $_POST['action2'] ) && $_POST['action2'] == 'bulk-delete' )
        ) {

            $delete_ids = esc_sql( $_POST['bulk-delete'] );

            // loop over the array of record IDs and delete them
            foreach ( $delete_ids as $id ) {
                self::delete_customer( $id );

            }

            // esc_url_raw() is used to prevent converting ampersand in url to "#038;"
                // add_query_arg() return the current url
                wp_redirect( esc_url_raw(add_query_arg()) );
            exit;
        }
    }

}


class SP_Plugin {

    // class instance
    static $instance;

    // customer WP_List_Table object
    public $customers_obj;

    // class constructor
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'set-screen-option', [ __CLASS__, 'set_screen' ], 10, 3 );
        add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'plugin_menu' ] );
    }


    public static function set_screen( $status, $option, $value ) {
        return $value;
    }

    public function plugin_menu() {

        $hook = add_menu_page(
            'Sitepoint WP_List_Table Example',
            'SP WP_List_Table',
            'manage_options',
            'wp_list_table_class',
            [ $this, 'plugin_settings_page' ]
        );

        add_action( "load-$hook", [ $this, 'screen_option' ] );

    }


    /**
    * Plugin settings page
    */
    public function plugin_settings_page() {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>WP_List_Table Class Example</h2>

            <div id="poststuff">
                <div id="post-body" class="metabox-holder columns-2">
                    <div id="post-body-content">
                        <div class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
                            <form method="post">
                                <?php
                                $this->customers_obj->prepare_items();
                                $this->customers_obj->display(); ?>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }

    /**
    * Screen options
    */
    public function screen_option() {

        $option = 'per_page';
        $args   = [
            'label'   => 'Customers',
            'default' => 5,
            'option'  => 'customers_per_page'
        ];

        add_screen_option( $option, $args );

        $this->customers_obj = new Customers_List();
    }


    /** Singleton instance */
    public static function get_instance() {
        if ( ! isset( self::$instance ) ) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function () {
    SP_Plugin::get_instance();
} );
```

I know this is a frequently asked question here, but I tried to search a lot before asking and nothing helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code uses another method to show a "sucess" or "deleted" message without using wp_redirect: https://github.com/pmbaldha/WP-Custom-List-Table-With-Database-Example

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain *this* is your problem, *but*... I believe your "no_items" function should return the value, not echo it.  If there are no items, that would lead to a "headers already sent" when the redirect is fired.  Try it like this:

```
/** Text displayed when no customer data is available */
public function no_items() {
    return __( 'No customers avaliable.', 'sp' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it does not work for me